# regex pattern not returning matches

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, vb.net

i have following regex code to check all url in string and add hyperlink to it

```
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "google.com is here http://www.google.com"
    //  str += "af sfda sdajsd a"
     //   str += " google.com"



var patt1 =  /(\b(?:(https?|ftp):\/\/)?((?:www\d{0,3}\.)?([a-z0-9.-]+\.(?:[a-z]{2,4}|museum|travel)(?:\/[^\/\s]+)*))\b)/g;

    var result = str.replace(patt1, function(url) {
        return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
    });

    alert(result)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this works fine but when i use the same pattern on server side it does not return any matches. So what is that i am doing wrong

my vb.net code is as follows

```
Dim regex As New Regex("/(\b(?:(https?|ftp):\/\/)?((?:www\d{0,3}\.)?([a-z0-9.-]+\.(?:[a-z]{2,4}|museum|travel)(?:\/[^\/\s]+)*))\b)/g;")

 Dim mactches As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(strtemp)

            For Each match As Match In mactches
                strtemp = strtemp.Replace(match.Value, "<a target='_blank' href='" & match.Value & "'>" & match.Value & "</a>")
            Next
```

Comment: Remember that the `/` at the beginning and end of a JS regex literal are not actually part of the expression, they're the JS regex literal syntax... (Also, you might want to [edit] your question title.)

Comment: @nnnnnn my bad bro the. i just removed / and /g from the pattern and it worked properly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just removed / and /g from the pattern and it worked properly.